# Averiguar largo de documento con ITextSharp C#

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Quería saber sí existe forma de saber hasta que altura es que llega lo escrito en un pdf generado por medio de la clase `ItextSharp.text.Document`;

Por ejemplo, a la hora de generar un documento pdf con ItextSharp, se que solo tengo que ejecutar la instrucción `document.PageSize` y obtengo un `ItextSharp.text.Rectangle`, del cual puedo sacar las medidas de la página. Pero si la página tuviera una altura de 1000, pero sí lo escrito en dicho documento llegara hasta la mitad, el texto llegaría hasta los 500. Este número 500 es el que me interesa averiguar.

Aquí agrego lo que hago.

```
Rectangle rec= new Rectangle(1000, 215);
Document document = new Document(rec, 10,10,10,10);
Font fuente = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD);
Lineas = obtenerLineas() //obtengo las líneas para agregar al documento
document.Open();
foreach(linea in Lineas)
{
  Paragraph textLine = new Paragraph(linea.texto, fuente);
  document.add(textLine);
}
document.Close();
```

**Nota:** las clases Rectangle, Document, Font, Pagraph son de la librería ITextSharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto

```
int height = document.Document.PageSize.Height - textLine.TotalLeading;
```